# Is $L=\{\langle M_1,M_2\rangle|L(M_1)\cap L(M_2)\neq \emptyset \}$ R, RE or coRE?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

Below is the language, determine (R), (RE), (coRE). and prove your answer.

$L=\{\langle M_1,M_2\rangle|M_1,M_2$ are Turing-machines and $L(M_1)\cap L(M_2)\neq \emptyset \}$

**Attempt:** I Think the language $L\in RE$ Because we need to use $U-MT$ such that we check all the  $L(M_1)\cap L(M_2)\neq \emptyset$ to see if all language in the Machines at least 1 accept to be not equal to the empty set so it can be infinity and the last one will be in both language in the machines.

I would like someone will verify and clarify the situation, and give me some steps to prove that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $L$ is not recursive: there is an easy reduction from $L_{ne}=\{\langle M\rangle \mid \mathcal{L}(M) \neq \emptyset\}$ which is a well known non-recursive language (for the reduction, just use a TM $M_2$ such that $\mathcal{L}(M_2) = \Sigma^*$).

Now, $L$ is indeed recursively enumerable. The intuition behind this is the following ; considering inputs ordered lexicographically:

```
n ← 1
repeat:
    simulate n computation steps for the n first inputs for M1 and M2
    n ← n + 1
until:
    M1 and M2 accepts the same input x
return true
```

If $\langle M_1, M_2\rangle\in L$, then the previous algorithm will stop and return `true`. Otherwise, the algorithm will never stop.

Finally, since $L$ is not R but RE, it means that $\overline{L}$ is not RE, so $L$ is not coRE.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your answer.
Second, you mean this $L \in RE\backslash R$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Okay thanks, in the algorithm I did not understand the definition of n, what is this n like a counter step?

Comment: That's it. The principle is called [*dovetailing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)).